# How to pass i18n localization text in to property of array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, i18next, react-i18next

Hi I'm trying to pass i18n localization text in to property of the array but it showing me the error on compiling.

```
 const columns = [
{
  name:  {i18n.t('Stock Data')},
  selector: 'stockSymbol'
},
{
  name: 'Stock Name',
  selector: 'stockNameEn'
}]
```

The error is saying that , expected . how can I solve it ?

Comment: `name:  i18n.t('Stock Data')` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to make it clear:

In plain JavaScript (except jsx) `{}` means an object or a code block that's why it's not what you want.

`i18n.t('Stock Data')` returns a string that's why `name:  i18n.t('Stock Data')` is a solution.